# How do I reload, clear or redirect a PHPmailer form after submitting?

Tags: javascript, php, phpmailer

When the user submits the form, the data is not erased and he can spam mail. How can you clean up or redirect after submitting? The head hurts terribly, I have not found the answer for this form anywhere. Thank you, sorry for my english.
The form consists of the following code:

```js
  function send(event, php){
    console.log("Отправка запроса");
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', php, true);
    req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
    json = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (json.result == "success") {
            alert("Сообщение отправлено");
        } else {
            alert("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }
    // Если не удалось связаться с php файлом
    } else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

// Если не удалось отправить запрос. Стоит блок на хостинге
req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}
```

```html
<?php
// Файлы phpmailer
require 'phpmailer/PHPMailer.php';
require 'phpmailer/SMTP.php';
require 'phpmailer/Exception.php';
// Переменные, которые отправляет пользователь
$name = $_POST['name'];
$self = $_POST['self'];
$file = $_FILES['myfile'];

// Формирование самого письма
$title = "$name";
$body = "********";

// Настройки PHPMailer
$mail = new PHPMailer\PHPMailer\PHPMailer();
try {
    $mail->isSMTP();   
    $mail->CharSet = "UTF-8";
    $mail->SMTPAuth   = true;
    //$mail->SMTPDebug = 2;
    $mail->Debugoutput = function($str, $level) {$GLOBALS['status'][] = $str;};

    // Настройки вашей почты
    $mail->Host       = 'smtp.yandex.ru'; // SMTP сервера вашей почты
    $mail->Username   = '********'; // Логин на почте
    $mail->Password   = '********'; // Пароль на почте
    $mail->SMTPSecure = 'ssl';
    $mail->Port       = 465;
    $mail->setFrom('*******@yandex.ru', 'Заявка с сайта!'); // Адрес самой почты и имя отправителя

    // Получатель письма
    $mail->addAddress('********@gmail.com');  

if (!empty($file['name'][0])) {
    for ($ct = 0; $ct < count($file['tmp_name']); $ct++) {
        $uploadfile = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), sha1($file['name'][$ct]));
        $filename = $file['name'][$ct];
        if (move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'][$ct], $uploadfile)) {
            $mail->addAttachment($uploadfile, $filename);
            $rfile[] = "Файл $filename прикреплён";
        } else {
            $rfile[] = "Не удалось прикрепить файл $filename";
        }
    }   
}

// Отправка сообщения
$mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body = $body;    

if ($mail->send()) {$result = "success";} 
else {$result = "error";}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = "error";
    $status = "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}
// Отображение результата
echo json_encode(["result" => $result, "resultfile" => $rfile, "status" => $status]);
?>
```

Thank you so much again

Comment: after the request response redirect it using location.href = "url"

Comment: @Jerson I tried to insert this code at the end, but for some reason it does not work :(                                                                                       
        if(!$mail->send()) {
    echo 'Error';
} else {
    header('location: thank-you.html');
}

Comment: so the email is not sending properly

Answer (score 0):

Try this for redirecting

```
if ($mail->Send()) { 
        header("Location:file.php");//echo "Email Sent!";            
    }
```

Comment: *did i do the right thing? For some reason, the letters do not come, but the page reloads*               $mail->isHTML(true);
$mail->Subject = $title;
$mail->Body = $body;    
     
// Проверяем отравленность сообщения
if ($mail->send()) {$result = "success";} 
else {$result = "error";}

} catch (Exception $e) {
    $result = "error";
    $status = "Сообщение не было отправлено. Причина ошибки: {$mail->ErrorInfo}";
}

if ($mail->Send()) { 
        header("Location:file.php");//echo "Email Sent!";            
    }

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all, I didn’t think that I could make everything so easy.

```html
 function send(event, php){
    console.log("Отправка запроса");
    event.preventDefault ? event.preventDefault() : event.returnValue = false;
    var req = new XMLHttpRequest();
    req.open('POST', php, true);
    req.onload = function() {
    if (req.status >= 200 && req.status < 400) {
    json = JSON.parse(this.response);
        if (json.result == "success") {
            window.location.href = "site-adress";
        } else {
            alert("Ошибка. Сообщение не отправлено");
        }
    // Если не удалось связаться с php файлом
    } else {alert("Ошибка сервера. Номер: "+req.status);}}; 

// Если не удалось отправить запрос. Стоит блок на хостинге
req.onerror = function() {alert("Ошибка отправки запроса");};
req.send(new FormData(event.target));
}
```